# $plugins_dir has no effect

Tags: smarty

My code is:

```
    $this->plugins_dir[0] = SMARTY_DIR . 'plugins';
    $this->plugins_dir[1] = SMARTY_DIR . 'smarty_plugins';
```

and result is

ERRNO: 8
TEXT: Indirect modification of overloaded property Application::$plugins_dir has no effect

in Smarty 3.1.29

I have been finding for two days without solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you add plugin dirs to smarty. Maybe it worked in previous versions but not in 3. The correct way would be:

```
$smarty->setPluginsDir(SMARTY_DIR . 'plugins')
       ->addPluginsDir(SMARTY_DIR . 'smarty_plugins');
```

Comment: I have tried it:

    $this->setPluginsDir(SMARTY_DIR . 'plugins')
           ->addPluginsDir(SMARTY_DIR . 'smarty_plugins');

Not work.

Comment: what does var_dump($smarty->getPluginsDir()); show after you execute the previous code?

Comment: ERRNO: 8
TEXT: Undefined variable: smarty
LOCATION: C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop4\presentation\application.php, line 29, at July 13, 2016, 11:19 am
Showing backtrace:
Application.__construct() # line   16, file: C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop4\index.php



Fatal error: Call to a member function getPluginsDir() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop4\presentation\application.php on line 29

Comment: You must be using a variable name other than $smarty to initialize it (maybe $this?). Check for a line similar to "$variable = new Smarty;" and use the variable name you're using in the code I've provided instead of $smarty

Comment: After change $smarty in $this, I've got:

array(2) { [0]=> string(53) "C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop4\libs\smarty\libs\plugins\" [1]=> string(60) "C:\xampp\htdocs\tshirtshop4\libs\smarty\libs\smarty_plugins\" }

Comment: I have only parent::__construct();

Comment: Work!!! This code: 
    $this->setPluginsDir(array(
    SMARTY_DIR .'plugins',
    PRESENTATION_DIR . 'smarty_plugins',
));

Thank you all of you very much!